# Return a specific value only of the faster coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing a Kotlin Android application
In my app, I need to run multiple coroutines in parallel and I would like to return only the first not null value of the one that finishes first?

I used the select expression, sample found there: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/select-expression.html#selecting-deferred-values

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.selects.*
import java.util.*
    
fun CoroutineScope.asyncString(time: Int) = async {
    delay(time.toLong())
    null
}

fun CoroutineScope.asyncStringsList(): List<Deferred<String>> {
    val random = Random(3)
    return List(12) { asyncString(random.nextInt(1000)) }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val list = asyncStringsList()
    val result = select<String> {
        list.withIndex().forEach { (index, deferred) ->
            deferred.onAwait { answer ->
              answer
           }
        }
    }
    println(result)
}
```

In my case, it would be :

```
        list.withIndex().forEach { (index, deferred) ->
            deferred.onAwait { answer ->
              if (answer == null) return else answer
           }
        }
```

but I have this error:  'return' is not allowed here.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done much with `select` clauses, and I don't know how to selectively pick whether to reject a result and wait for the next one. (Seems like a critical missing feature.)

Here's a way I think you can do something similar using `channelFlow`. It launches parallel coroutines for each Deferred and they are emitted by the Flow in order, so you can then filter and pick the first one with `first()`.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val list = asyncStringsList()
    val result = channelFlow {
        list.forEach { launch { send(it.await()) } }
    }
        .filterNotNull()
        .first()
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try your code, it seems to work great. To be sure what `channelFlow` does, it completes when all its children completed ? So, suppose if the first async task returns the value needed (in my case, the first not null value), `channelFlow` will complete or wait ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can read in the documentation that the flow completes when the lambda block returns and all its children complete. So actually I take back what I said about wrapping in `coroutineScope` because I think that's redundant. The children already have a parent ProducerScope provided by the `channelFlow` builder. When you use a terminal operator like `first` or `take` on a Flow, it gets cancelled after that many elements are consumed, so all unfinished children coroutines will be cancelled. But since they are wrapping Deferreds, those Deferreds are still running.

Comment: If instead you just wrapped various coroutines declared directly in `channelFlow`, then the slower ones would end up getting cancelled.

Comment: Thanks, for your explanations. It's very clear. Would it no be better if instead to use `filterNotNull().first()` using `.firstOrNull { it != null }` to avoid `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: You could also use `filterNotNull().firstOrNull()` without a lambda. Just preference. It’s definitely easier to work with “orNull” than dealing with exceptions.